# How to get the text value of a CodeMirror-6 editor

Tags: javascript, codemirror-6

I'm playing with CodeMirror to check if I can use it in our site to allow the user to write c# scripts. I can made a sample easily but I can't find any documentation nabout to get the text value of the editor to send through a form post.

JS Source:

```
import {StreamLanguage} from "@codemirror/language"
import {csharp} from "@codemirror/legacy-modes/mode/clike"

import {EditorView, basicSetup} from "codemirror"

let editor = new EditorView({
  extensions: [basicSetup, StreamLanguage.define(csharp)],
  parent: document.getElementById('_formengine_script')
})
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf8>
<h1>CodeMirror!</h1>
<div id="_formengine_script"></div>
<script src="editor.bundle.js"></script>
```

I think that there must be various ways to solve it but I can't any of them. I've found a lot of information on CodeVersion 5, but I would prefer to use the latest version.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into the same problem. The codemirror 6 documentation is odd. It contains lots of deep dives but lacks of the basics.

I ended up looking into the unit tests rather than the documentation. You find there a nice test in the [history module](https://github.com/codemirror/history/blob/3c41743067bc405faa0b9cbe0c81ef1e6f7cd627/test/test-history.ts#L36), the test changes the document and then checks if the document contains the expected data.

Based on this, assuming `editor` is a reference to your `EditorView`, you endup with the following:

```
editor.state.doc.toString();
```

Update:
Just after writing this I stumbled upon https://codemirror.net/docs/migration/ just go there to  the "Getting the Document and Selection" chapter. It contains the examples your searched for.

Comment: Thanks for yout contribution, but your code cannot help me to get the selection neither the link you provided. Note that I'm newbie in ES6 modules and I'm a bit lost. My goal will be to get the selection on the javascript console.

Comment: @user2468193 Interesting to know how you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Editor allows to mark more than one selection range at once (example below)
[image]

You can get all of the selected ranges using this piece of code

```
editor.state.selection.ranges
```

Here an example how to get first selected text from all ranges.

```
let firstRange = editor.state.selection.ranges.at(0);
let selectedText = editor.state.doc.toString().substring(firstRange.from,firstRange.to)
console.log(selectedText); //output: 'ECT * FR'
```

The multimode selection can be disabled, but the way which you access the selected range stay the same.